# Caching account data

Tags: iri-legacy-api, javascript

Reading through the documentation for the [IOTA Javascript Library](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) I realized the method `iota.api.getAccountData` can be provided with an starting index:

```
iota.api.getAccountData(seed, {start: 123}, function(error, res) {
  [...]
});
```

As you may already know, this index specifies the address at which the library will start finding transactions, ignoring all seed's previous addresses.

---

Now, here's the question: Is there any similar mechanism for caching transactions, so that when calling `getAccountData` it will fetch just the newly created ones since the last call?